# How to handle if tab icon press is the current screen with react navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

How would I be able to detect and implement an event handler for when a user presses on a tab button for the current screen?

Use Case: I'm trying to implement a camera button in the tab bar - navigating to the camera tab opens the camera viewer and changes the tab icon to a take picture icon, tapping on this camera tab button again while in the camera tab view will take a picture.

I currently implement the tabBarOnPress function on the tab navigation, but need to pass that event to the screen itself.

```
  tabBarOnPress: ({ previousScene, scene, jumpToIndex }) => {
    if (previousScene.routeName === 'Camera' && scene.route.routeName === 'Camera') {
      console.log('fire camera picture');
    } else {
      jumpToIndex(scene.index);
    }
  }
```

Ideally I'd like to be able to set an onPress or event handler on the camera screen.  How should I trigger a method in the target scene - should I pass a navigation prop or variable and use some sort of navigation received event on the screen itself?

Comment: Wouldn't it be much simpler if you overlay a second button when the cam view is opened and take the picture with it? This way you can separate the cam view logic and navigation also you wouldn't have to pass any complicated params. Just an idea though...

Comment: I think it seems a bit weird to have a button on top of the existing nav button.  In my opinion I think it would be better to co-locate the camera code in the camera screen code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting a param on componentWillMount let me get a reference to the method

TabNavigator options:

```
  tabBarOnPress: ({ previousScene, scene, jumpToIndex }) => {
    if (previousScene.routeName === 'Camera' && scene.route.routeName === 'Camera') {
      scene.route.params.takePicture();
    } else {
      jumpToIndex(scene.index);
    }
  }
```

CameraScreen

```
  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.navigation.setParams({
      takePicture: this.takePicture,
    });

    // possibly we might need to also implement below for this issue - 
    // https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/2955
    // InteractionManager.runAfterInteractions(() => {
    //   this.props.navigation.setParams({
    //     scrollToTop: this._scrollToTop,
    //   });
    // })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Screen component has a prop called `listeners` with that you can do the following

```
    <TabScreen
      name="YourScreenComponent"
      component={YourScreenComponent}
      listeners={({ navigation }) => ({
        tabPress: () => {
          if (navigation.isFocused()) console.log('FIRE CAMARA HERE!');
        },
      })}
    />
```